# Python Server / Java Client "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, python, client-server, serversocket

I am communicating using TCP Socket.

While Working, a problem arises

- Client can't make 'Socket' Instance.
- Strange Point is that (In Server using Python)

  Using 'socket' class in python don't cause problem,
  but using 'SocketServer.TCPServer' class in python cause problem

This is my environment.

- Server : Python
- Client : Java / Many Users will try connect.

Server Code (using Python):

1. SooMain.py

   if **name** == "**main**":

   ```
   server = SooServer('localhost', PORT_DEBUG, SooRequestHandler)
   server.serve_forever()
   ```
2. SooServer.py

   ```
   class SooServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
   "This is Server For Project201201"

   def __init__(self, 
                host='localhost', 
                port=PORT_DEBUG,
                handler=SooRequestHandler):
       #SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
       SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
       print "SooServer <State> __init__"
       self.abort=0
       self.timeout=10

   def shutdown(self):
       SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.shutdown(self)
       print "SooServer <State> shutdown"
   ```

Client Code (using Java):

1. TestJava.java

   ```
   public class TestJava {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       try {

           String[] aStrData = {
           "Test",
           "Test"          };

           InetAddress m_oInetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(DEBUG_ADDR); 
           Socket m_oSocket = new Socket(m_oInetAddr, DEBUG_PORT); //This Line Makes Exception!!!!!

           PrintWriter out = 
                   new PrintWriter(
                   new BufferedWriter(
                   new OutputStreamWriter(m_oSocket.getOutputStream())), true);

           int nNumData = aStrData.length;
           out.println(Integer.toString(nNumData));

           for (int i=0 ; i<nNumData ; i++) {                  
               out.println(aStrData[i]);
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }   
     }
   }
   ```

Error Code (using Java):

```
Releated Line : Socket m_oSocket = new Socket(m_oInetAddr, DEBUG_PORT);


java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at TestJava.main(TestJava.java:51)
```